# Await window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, csv, export-to-csv

So this might be a weird scenario but I have an endpoint (GET, that returns CSV) which I am calling using window.location.href = "URL". This call can take some time due to the heavy data load and for that reason I would want a loading spinner to appear on the page.

(Using React)
At the beginning of the onClick function I am setting the state for the loading spinner to true, calling window.location.href and then setting the state to false.

I have tried everything I could however I can't get the spinner to load and hide properly once the api has completed. I have tried wrapping it in a promise and trying .then but still no luck.

Any ideas? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
export = () => {

    this.setState({loading:true});

    window.location.href = "url";

    this.setState({loading:false});

}
```

Comment: `this.setState({false});` won't get called because setting the url will reload the page

Comment: Also, `setState` isn't really synchronous, a lot of times react will batch the `setState` operations, so the execution doesn't really proceed in the way you are thinking right now..

Comment: @Liam - That depends on the response. If the response sends `Content-Disposition: attachment`, it may well just trigger a download dialog without replacing the current page.

Comment: True dat @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Liam I doesn't reload the page, just triggers the download

Comment: How big is the data? Is it feasible to just download it in in background (with an ajax call), and than show download dialog client-side? I think it can be done pretty seamlessly with blob urls or something like this.

Comment: I guess ajax+[FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) is the solution you need. There is also StreamSaver.js that you could use in case your data is too big. I can write an answer later if that seems like a good solution for you.

Comment: And, btw, you should really add a bit about just triggering a download to the question, it is crucial information, and not visible at all.

Comment: @Frax I think StreamSaver.js may be a solution. I have tried using a Ajax call but iI wasn't too sure how to read/write the stream that got sent back into a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

#### If the page is going to be replaced by the csv...

...then just fix the typo (you have `loaction` instead of `location`) and remove `this.setState({false})` (which is also a typo, but which you don't want). The spinner will start, probably, and eventually the page will be replaced with the CSV.

#### If the page is going to remain in place...

...then the way I've done this is to have a cookie that tells me whether the response has been received:

1. Make sure the cookie isn't set.
2. Make sure the response sends the cookie.
3. Use a timer loop in the main page looking for the cookie value.

So in your case, something along the lines of:

```
export = () => {
    this.setState({loading:true});
    this.clearTheCookieValue();
    window.location.href = "url";
    this.cookieWatchTimer = setInterval(() => {
        if (/*the cookie value has now been set*/) {
            clearInterval(this.cookieWatchTimer);
            this.cookieWatchTimer = 0;
            this.setState({loading: fals});
        }
    });
}
```

...and in `componentWillUnmount`, clear that interval timer.